# Coordinates are wrong

Tags: coordinate-system

In QGIS 2.13.2 I have a google map and a shapefile. Now I want to print it with all the necessary items, but I have a big problem with the coordinates.
First of all, the coordinates just appear when I use the WGS84 / Pseudo Mercator (EPSG: 3857). If I try to use the normal WGS 84 nothing appears. Why is that?

The other problem is, that my coordinates show something completely different than they should be. I looked them up and its somewhere in Africa, although I need the coordinates for a place in Germany. Did I make a mistake with georeferencing the shapefile?

Comment: Somewhere in Africa as in at 0,0 off the SW coast?  Are all of your features + data frame in the same coordinate system?

Comment: I am kind of lost. I use a google map and added to that a shapefile, which I downloaded and those are in EPSG: 31467, DHDN / Gauss-Kruger zone 3). Do I have to transform them first to the same like Google maps use? (I think that is the EPSG: 3857? And how would I do that?)

I thought it was ok, but as soon as I use the print composer, I get different coordinates that led me to nowhere. For example as  longitude: 984000.0 and latitude 6138000.0.

Did I make a mistake right from the begin? Sorry I am new to all of that…

Comment: Hmmm... did you accidentally flip your X and Y coordinates? (Lat=Y Lon=X). I don't mean that to be condescending, I make this mistake still.

Comment: Do you mean when I search for them? I tried both ways and it doesn’t work. 
Shouldn’t it be something with 8. and 48. for Germany? 

I have no idea what I could do or how to  correct the coordinates…

Comment: I just tried it again with a Open Street Map and there  I have the same problem that they don´t show me correct coordinates. With web based data it should be EPSG: 3857, correct?

Comment: You need to change your shapefile's coordinate system (bring it to either EPSG 3857 or EPSG 4326, I've had both overlay correctly on google maps with no issues before), what @StevenFerronato is probably asking is whether you accidentally switch your Lat and Longitudes when you were making the shapefile (the X and Y can get confusing) but I don't think that you did because you downloaded the shapefile and didn't enter the data manually.

Comment: I changed my shapefiles coordinate system to that ones you said, but then the shapefile is not at the correct place anymore. I know where the shapefile should be, since I could see them in the map before downloading it. 

I tried it again with Open Street Map and no shapefile in it or editing something and I also get the wrong coordinates. Is there something else that could be the problem? Maybe some start settings?

Comment: Did you save the changes you made in the coordinate system? Where did you get the shapefile from, can you provide a sample?

Comment: I downloaded the shapefile from this page: 
http://www4.lubw.baden-wuerttemberg.de/servlet/is/245731/

Comment: there you have to scroll down to the “Wasserschutzgebietszonen” – protected water zones. This is the shapefile I used. Besides that, I used the google map (which I got through the Open Layer plugin).

Actually I don’t think that the problem is the shapefile, since I tried to do the same with a map and nothing else on it, and it didn’t work neither…

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! hope we find a solution.. or my mistake :)

Comment: What happened when you used the map without anything on it? What did you try to do with it?

Comment: I just tried to get the right coordinates in the print composer (to show them on the side). But I got the same like with the shapefile.

Comment: Even when I am in the QGIS 2.12.3 and I click on my area of interest, it shows me at coordinate the 6137854 (same like in the print composer), although this area should hace coordinates with something like 48..., as the normal google maps shows me.. am I that wrong? So its not an issue of the Print Composer, but already before, right?

Comment: Now I changed my map from the EPSG: 3857 to the EPSG: 4326. Than I get my coordinates right, but as soon as I want to see the shapefile its not there anymore where it should be. And when I also change it to EPSG: 4326 its not there at all...

Comment: You are encountering these problems because QGIS uses on the fly projection which can get really confusing. Just convert your shapefile to WGS84 and try to overlay it on the map.

Comment: So you mean i have to convert QGIS to WGS84 and also the shapefile? when I convert QGIS to that one, the coordinates are allright, but when i do it with the shapefile it just disappears (or is at some place far away…).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35593/discussion-on-question-by-freya-coordinates-are-wrong).

Answer (score 0):

When I open the shapefile and add a basemap to it (keeping it in the same coordinate system) this is how it looks[image]

Is this how it overlays on your end as well? or do you not have it showing at all?

Comment: yes, this is how it looks like in my QGIS too. I guess I can’t explain myself very good, but what I want to do is, put this image in the print composer and get the right coordinates. But as soon as I do that, the coordinates are wrong (and show me someplace in Africa). When I change the google map to EPSG 4326, my shapefile doesn’t fit anymore, but the coordinates are right. And as soon as I change my shapefile also to the EPSG 4326, the shapefile is at a completely different place. Does the same happen to you?